# JQGRID : passing multiple ur parameter values

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have the following JQgrid. Which passes parameter values Symbol and Description through url. 
for some reason the 2nd parameter is not getting passed.

Also how can I highlight a link as hyper link?

```
 formatoptions: {
                            baseLinkUrl: "http://www.cnn.com",
                            idName: "",
                            addParam: function (options) {
                                var urlparam += "bankid="+options.rowData.Symbol;
                                urlparam  += "&timePeriod="+options.rowData.ShareQuantity;
                                return urlparam ;
                            }
                        }
```

[My FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/615qovew/78/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then you can return object from the `addParam` callback:

```
formatter: "showlink",
formatoptions: {
    baseLinkUrl: "http://www.cnn.com",
    idName: "",
    addParam: function (options) {
        return {
            bankid: options.rowData.Symbol,
            timePeriod:options.rowData.ShareQuantity
        };
    }
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/615qovew/79/. Free jqGrid will use [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) to convert the object properties to URL parameters. It produces links with URLs like

```
http://www.cnn.com/?bankid=BBB&timePeriod=9623
http://www.cnn.com/?bankid=GPSC&timePeriod=49612
http://www.cnn.com/?bankid=WEC&timePeriod=20638
```

Comment: thank you , I tried it but for some reason i am not getting the values  https://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/615qovew/91/            return {
                      certid: options.rowData.CertificateNumber,
                      timePeriod:options.rowData.timePeriod
                  };

Comment: @user244394: You use the data which has no `CertificateNumber` and `timePeriod` properties in the input data. See exactly `jsonData.rows`. You just included `bank` part in `jsonData`.

Comment: @user244394: Moreover, if you need have access to the data properties, which are not in columns, then you have to add the properties in `additionalProperties` option: `additionalProperties: ["Num1", "CertificateNumber", "timePeriod"]`. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/615qovew/92/

Comment: Thanks that worked.. how do you about underlining a hyberlink or anything to make the hyperlink obvious  to show a user the that "Symbol" is a url link .https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/615qovew/92/

Comment: @user244394: You included Bootstrap CSS in your original demo, thus the Bootstrap CSS applies `<a>` elements. You can remove the CSS if you don't need it. You can add CSS `.ui-jqgrid a { text-decoration: underline; }` (or just `a { text-decoration: underline; }`) to solve the problem. You can add additionally the rule like `.ui-jqgrid  .jqgrow.ui-state-hover a { text-decoration: underline; }` to hold showing the underline in hovering rows too.

Comment: -Thank you you are the best very detailed :)